# How to give value to Table Headers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Context**

I have a table inside a pagination. I want to "On table header click, sort by the column". I must query with `order by 'column'` added because I only fetch 50 rows at once. So sorting in the table won't work. Currently I achieved this by giving each `th` different ids. But I want to use class to achieve this. It would've been possible if `th` can hold values. But it seems like it can't.

**Question**

How can I associate an arbitrary string with an HTML element?

Comment: it's a bit fuzzy. make a simple example (as recommended here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example )

Comment: If you want to associate an arbitrary string with an HTML element (like a `th`), you might want to use `data-attributes` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). You can set a custom attribute called, say, 'my-string' in the HTML with `<th data-my-string="Mal shot first">` (or in a script with `myHeader.setAttribute("data-my-string", "Mal shot first");`). And you can use the value with `let str = myHeader.dataset.myString` -- The `dataset` property contains all the data-attributes (converted from kebab-case to camelCase, with the `data-` prefix removed).

Comment: @Cat could you post this as an answer please?

Comment: Yeah, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to associate an arbitrary string with an HTML element (like a `th`), **you might want to use [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)**.

You can set a custom attribute called, say, 'my-string' in the HTML with:

```
<th data-my-string="Mal shot first">...
```

Or in a script with:

```
myHeader.setAttribute("data-my-string", "Mal shot first");
```

And you can use the value with:

```
let str = myHeader.dataset.myString; // Note the unusual syntax
```

The `.dataset` property contains all the data-attributes (each converted from kebab-case to camelCase, with the `data-` prefix removed).

(I wasn't sure what you meant by "I want to use class to achieve this", but since you indicated that "it would've been possible if `th` can hold values", I thought you might find this technique useful.)

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can get/set by following method; To get `$(something).data("myString")`, To set `$(something).data("myString", "123")`

Answer (score 1):

you just need to get the cellIndex

```js
const  myTable = document.getElementById('my-table')
  ;
  myTable.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('thead td')) return
  let TD = e.target
  TD.className = (TD.className==='')? 'upOrder' : (TD.className==='upOrder') ? 'downOrder' : '';
  
  console.clear()
  console.log('col index=', TD.cellIndex, 'order=', TD.className , 'text=', TD.textContent )
  }
```

```css
/* cosmetic part */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  }
thead {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
tbody {
  background-color: #b4c5d8;
  }
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  }

thead td > i.fa { display:none; }
thead td.upOrder   > i.fa-caret-up   { display:inline; }
thead td.downOrder > i.fa-caret-down { display:inline; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" />

<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td> col_0
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>  
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ></i> 
      </td> 
      <td> col_1
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>  
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ></i> 
      </td> 
      <td> col_2
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>  
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ></i> 
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>elm col_0</td> <td>elm col_1</td> <td>elm col_2</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>elm col_0</td> <td>elm col_1</td> <td>elm col_2</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>elm col_0</td> <td>elm col_1</td> <td>elm col_2</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>elm col_0</td> <td>elm col_1</td> <td>elm col_2</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```